# Datatables pagination move to page after adding row

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using the datatables.js plugin to help with pagination and such.

Part of the functionality is that they can 'add comments' to the table. I have it doing so successfully. However, if the comment goes to the next page I need the pagination to move to the new comment instead of staying on the first page or moving to the first page.

I was trying to find some different options to help do this, but was unsuccessful.

My Jquery looks like this.

```
$('.addComment').on('click', function () {

        var newCom = $('.newCommentArea').find('input').val();

        var rowNode = commentTable
            .row.add(['Date', 'User', newCom])
            .draw()
            .node();

        $(rowNode)
            .css('background-color', 'lightyellow')
            .animate({
                color: 'black'
            });
    });
```

The html is just a standard table.

```
<table class='commentTable'>
  <thead>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so you are saying that when you add a new comment it moves to the next page and you want newly added comment on the first page?

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER Kind of. When a new comment is made I would like it to move to the page that comment is on.

Comment: provide some HTML

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER It's literately just a basic table....but it's now in the queswtion

Comment: Maybe a plug-in, kind of depends if it is the "last" or somewhere else in the order.  https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()

Comment: @zazvorniki check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var commentTable = $('.commentTable').DataTable();
$('.addComment').on('click', function () {
    var newCom = $('.newCommentArea').val();
    var rowNode = commentTable.row.add(['Date', 'User', newCom]).draw(false).node(); 
    //table.row.add([newCom]).draw(false);
    commentTable.page('last').draw(false);
    $(rowNode)
         .css('background-color', 'lightyellow')
         .animate({
             color: 'black'
         });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input class="newCommentArea" />
<button class="addComment">
 ADD
</button>
<table class='commentTable'>
  <thead>
   <th>Date</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

following changes have been made for your code:

```
var rowNode = commentTable.row.add(['Date', 'User', newCom]).draw(false).node(); 
commentTable.page('last').draw(false);
```